# Change update frequency of App Store in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update, notifications

The Mac App Store on Mac OS X (10.8.3) notifies me frequently about new app updates by showing a little popup. How can I change the update frequency or the way Mac OS X notifies me?

Comment: Related questions: [60881](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60881/how-do-i-turn-off-app-store-notifications-in-mountain-lion), [72784](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72784/how-can-i-permanently-dismiss-updates-available-notifications)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Launch Terminal, found in /Applications/Utilities/ and enter the following command:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate ScheduleFrequency 3
```

Set the number at the end to the number in days between checking for available software updates, the example uses **3 days**

Comment: Thanks! Tried it and it seems to work fine. Do you know if this settings survives updates?

Comment: Not sure, but it should, as it would be pointless otherwise. Please don't forget to accept my answer if it is the answer is satisfactory. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this checks for Mac App Store apps, and not just Software Updates for OS X itself?