# Change update frequency of App Store in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

Similar to [Change update frequency of app store in Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87351/change-update-frequency-of-app-store-in-mountain-lion)

Is there a way to change the frequency the App Store checks for updates in Yosemite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same command still works in Yosemite:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate ScheduleFrequency 3
```

The integer represents the check interval in days.