# How do I disable App Store notifications when auto-updating software?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, notifications, auto-update

I have OSX Mavericks installed.

While I actually DO enjoy the notification center feature (and want to keep it turned on), I also am very particular about which notifications I want to see, and how. The notifications area of System Preferences does a great job of handling this the way I'd like it to. However, the App Store doesn't seem to show up there.

I like having my apps automatically updated, and don't want to turn that feature off, but I definitely don't need to be distracted by a banner popup every time an app gets updated. It happens a few times per day, and it's annoying and dilutes the value of notifications that actually ARE relevant (i.e. I start ignoring them because there are low-value notifications popping up all the time).

So, my question is this: How can I turn notifications off for the App Store, and leave the automatic update feature and notification center turned on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any apps installed to try this with, but this looked like it might work. The solution is for Mountain Lion, not Mavericks, so it may have changed.

[How do I turn off App Store notifications in Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60881/how-do-i-turn-off-app-store-notifications-in-mountain-lion)

> I just discovered the missing solution here:
>   http://osxdaily.com/2012/11/15/stop-software-update-mac-os-x/
>
> You can selectively disable notifications about specific software
>   updates you don't care about (like useless App updates) by
>   control-clicking the update inside the App Store to reveal a hidden
>   "Hide Update" option.
>
> This is best for those who want to keep Notification Center active for
>   all its other uses (calendar alarms, etc.) and who also want to be
>   notified about critical software updates. It should permanently mute
>   notifications about certain software updates (until that software
>   comes out with a new update).

Comment: Sadly, that answer only applies to Apple products, and not to other ones. However, the answers found in that article are about the most relevant ones available, and it looks like in the current version of OSX, that's the best I'm going to get... so I'll up-vote and mark this as answered. Thanks!